# How to create lists in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony framework. I'd like to create a list of records that would look like this:

[image]

I need some filters at the top, list of items in the middle and pagination at the bottom. List should have to support both editable and read only mode. In read only mode user could just browse the data while in edit mode he would be able to update values in multiple fields and columns.

Since I'll be making a lot of these lists I'd like to use interface like Forms in Symfony2 rather than tweaking twig templates all the time.

Am I missing some functionality of Symfony Forms that could create lists like this? Is there some other common way to implement this? Can you give me hints which form related classes to extend to create support for lists?

Comment: What you're trying to do here, to me at least, seems best tackled with twitter bootstrap (for the CSS bit), and [the KNP paginator](http://knplabs.com/en/blog/knp-paginator-reborn), which is a more than capable paginator bundle for SF2. That said, I do feel that this question is slightly off-topic, as it doesn't really seem to deal with a specific code-related problem, it's more of a _"How do I get started with"_ kind of question (if you need a crash-course on SF2, check the Symfony cookbook on their site, it's quite good, really)

Comment: I already checked cookbook but it doesn't describe how to create lists. I see I can create them in twig, but I like Form building interface. Since I need editable lists which can have fields like forms I tried to debug forms to figure out where can I hook into. I see that I should replace PropertyPathMapper to handle rows of data but that is just a start.

So I hoped there is an easier solution to modifying forms to work like lists.

Comment: Using forms as lists is not that difficult, and surely doesn't require you to dig as deep as the `ProperyPathMapper`, a simple twig template and a nested, custom form type should do, both of which are covered by the symfony cookbook, and explained in detail in the symfony2 docs

Comment: maybe use datatables.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to turn Symfony forms into lists I created a new form type ListType which accepts arbitrary nested collection type. That way I can create lists with various columns. It will look something like:

```
class ListType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (empty($options['collection_type']) || !$options['collection_type'] instanceof AbstractType) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException();
        }
        $builder->add('rows', 'collection', array('type' => $options['collection_type']));
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
    }
    ...
}
```

I'll use $options array to provide or turn on and off other features like search filter and pagination.

In order to have an easy interface for displaying lists like:

```
{{ list(list) }}
```

I created Twig extension:

```
class ListExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('list', array($this, 'listFunction'), array('is_safe' => array('html'), 'needs_environment' => true))
        );
    }

    public function listFunction(\Twig_Environment $env, FormView $form)
    {
        return $env->resolveTemplate($this->defaultTemplate)->renderBlock('list', array('form' => $form));
    }
    ...
}
```

It renders "list" Twig block. I'll also add other sub blocks the same way. This extension provides greater feedom than "form" blocks.

I registered list extension as a service:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    my.twig.list.extension:
        class: MyBundle\Twig\Extension\ListExtension
        arguments: ["::my_theme.html.twig"]
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now I only have to create a form of my ListType and pass it an array of row entities.

Thanks to [Elias Van Ootegem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1230836/elias-van-ootegem) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

APYdataGridBundle perfect solution for this, [in there](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle/)